# NPM: How do I find the parent of a child package?

Tags: node.js, npm

I have a bunch of older packages (Maintaining an Angularjs (1.0) stack) and when I am installing I get warnings about outdated versions of packages:

```
npm WARN deprecated bower@1.3.12: ...psst! Your project can stop working at any moment because its dependencies can change. Prevent this by migrating to Yarn: https://bower.io/
blog/2017/how-to-migrate-away-from-bower/
npm WARN deprecated babel-preset-es2015@6.24.1:   Thanks for using Babel: we recommend using babel-preset-env now: please read babeljs.io/env to update! 
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@3.0.11: please upgrade to graceful-fs 4 for compatibility with current and future versions of Node.js
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@1.0.0: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@2.0.3: please upgrade to graceful-fs 4 for compatibility with current and future versions of Node.js
npm WARN deprecated tough-cookie@0.12.1: ReDoS vulnerability parsing Set-Cookie https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/130
npm WARN deprecated node-uuid@1.4.8: Use uuid module instead
npm WARN deprecated npmconf@2.1.2: this package has been reintegrated into npm and is now out of date with respect to npm
```

How do I find out which package is pulling these in?

`npm outdated` returns nothing.
`npm prune` prunes nothing.

**package.json**

```
{                                                           
  "devDependencies": {                                                          
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",                                                          
    "browser-sync-webpack-plugin": "^2.2.2",                                                          
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.1",                                                          
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.1.0",                                                          
    "css-loader": "^0.28.11",                                                          
    "file-loader": "^1.1.11",                                                          
    "pug-html-loader": "^1.1.5",                                                          
    "pug-loader": "^2.3.0",                                                          
    "graceful-fs": "^4.1.11",                                                          
    "minimatch": "^3.0.4",                                                          
    "node-sass": "^4.8.3",                                                          
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.7",                                                          
    "style-loader": "^0.20.3",                                                          
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.2.4",                                                          
    "webpack": "^4.3.0",                                                          
    "webpack-cli": "^2.0.13",                                                          
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.2"                                                          
  },                                                    
  "dependencies": {                                                          
    "@uirouter/angularjs": "latest",
    "ajv": "^6.3.0",                                                         
    "angular": "^1.6.9",                                                          
    "angular-translate": "^2.17.0",                                                          
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",                                                          
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",                                                          
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",                                                          
    "babel-register": "^6.26.0",                                                          
    "brfs": "^1.5.0",                                                          
    "browser-sync": "^2.23.6",                                                          
    "debowerify": "^1.4.1",                                                          
    "isparta": "^4.0.0",                                                          
    "jshint": "^2.9.5",                                                          
    "jshint-stylish": "^2.2.0",                                                          
    "postcss-loader": "^2.1.3",                                                          
    "pretty-hrtime": "^1.0.2",                                                          
    "pug": "^2.0.3",                                                          
    "tiny-lr": "^1.1.1"                                                          
  }                                                         
}
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You can do `npm ls --all`. It will give you a tree structure showing how dependencies fits together. Example below:

```
lms@nuc ~/src/ralphtheninja/slump (master)
$ npm ls --all                            
slump@2.0.3 /home/lms/src/ralphtheninja/slump
├─┬ bs58@4.0.1                 
│ └─┬ base-x@3.0.4                   
│   └── safe-buffer@5.1.1 deduped       
├── core-util-is@1.0.2             
├─┬ faucet@0.0.1              
│ ├── defined@0.0.0                  
│ ├── duplexer@0.1.1                    
│ ├── minimist@0.0.5                      
│ ├── sprintf@0.1.5                      
│ ├─┬ tap-parser@0.4.3
│ │ ├── inherits@2.0.3 deduped
│ │ └─┬ readable-stream@1.1.14
│ │   ├── core-util-is@1.0.2 deduped
│ │   ├── inherits@2.0.3 deduped
│ │   ├── isarray@0.0.1
│ │   └── string_decoder@0.10.31
│ ├─┬ tape@2.3.3
│ │ ├── deep-equal@0.1.2
│ │ ├── defined@0.0.0 deduped
│ │ ├── inherits@2.0.3 deduped
│ │ ├── jsonify@0.0.0
│ │ ├── resumer@0.0.0 deduped
│ │ └── through@2.3.8 deduped
│ └─┬ through2@0.2.3
│   ├── readable-stream@1.1.14 deduped
│   └─┬ xtend@2.1.2
│     └── object-keys@0.4.0
├─┬ rc@1.2.6
│ ├── deep-extend@0.4.2
│ ├── ini@1.3.5
│ ├── minimist@1.2.0
│ └── strip-json-comments@2.0.1
├── safe-buffer@5.1.1
```

If you're wondering about a specific package, you can do `npm ls <package>`, which will show that sub tree.

You can also do `npm ls --json` to get it in json formatted output. Useful if you want to analyze it programmatically.

EDIT: Original post suggested using `npm ls` but newer versions of `npm ls` only displays a flat list.

Comment: this just shows a flat list for me

Comment: @a2f0 You are probably using a newer version of `npm`. Try `npm ls --all`.

Answer (score 4):

you can use command `npm ls contextify PACKAGE_NAME`

for example, I was trying to trace a package's parent packages. The package name is **app-builder-bin**.

```
npm ls contextify app-builder-bin
```

I got bellow output:

```
+-- electron-builder@21.0.15
| `-- builder-util@21.0.15
|   `-- app-builder-bin@3.3.0
`-- electron-builder-squirrel-windows@22.14.13
  `-- builder-util@22.14.13
    `-- app-builder-bin@3.7.1
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you upgrade your dependencies by using `npm-check-updates`.
You can install with: `npm install -g npm-check-updates`
Then by runnig `ncu` gives you a report of outdated packages or `ncu -u` updates the `package.json`.
More info about `ncu` [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates).

Otherwise, package-lock.json can give you information about dependencies of dependencies. Alternatively, `npm ls` can give you a report.

Comment: This is useful, and looks like it will help my upgrade a bit, but I'm trying to find out if there is a general way to do this, even if a package isn't stale.

Answer (score 0):

show only parents tree of certain sub :
Run it inside package root

```bash
npm ls --all | head -n $(npm ls --all | grep -n <package-name> | cut -d':' -f1)
```

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34667075)